# How do you prevent the SIP from ever showing in Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile

We have a full screen app in WM6.5, and when a message box pops up, about 1/2 a second later, so does the sip panel.

Is there a way to prevent it from popping up.

Right now we have a timer that hides it, but this is a hack, and we'd like a better solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a timer, then called the API's to close the SIP